# How to verify wildfly web server is using added keystore file for https connection?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, wildfly-10

I have created a self-signed certificate(public_certificate.crt), private key file(private_key.pem). and these are stored in keystore file keystore.jks.

I have configured the same keystore.jks file in the standalone.xml file of widlfly 10 in two section as:

**Section 1:**

```
 <security-realm name="UndertowRealm">
    <server-identities>
      <ssl>
         <keystore path="keystore.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="changeit" />
      </ssl>
    </server-identities>
  </security-realm>
```

**Section 2:**

```
<server name="default-server">
   <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
   <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="UndertowRealm" enable http2="true"/>
   <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
      <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
      <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
      <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
    </host>
 </server>
```

I have restarted the server, now when i am accessing the wildfly url(https://localhost:8443) it is coming as "Not Secure" in the browser url section of chrome.

I am having two question related to it:

1. With or Without configuring the standalone.xml file with our keystore, chrome is mentioning "Not Secure" in browser URL section. it might be because i am using self-signed certificate. but my question is, how will i know that my self-signed certificate is being used by Wildfly.
2. Is there any way to avoid "Not Secure" warning and it should be coming as "Lock" symbol in the browser for self-signed certificate.

Comment: Click on 'Not secure' and where it says 'Certificate (invalid)' with the tooltip 'show certificate' click on that and, incredible as it may seem, it _shows the certificate_. Note that if wildfly doesn't have _some_ keystore to use, you won't even get this far, you'll get a page with ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH. To have a self-signed cert be accepted by Chrome, you must manually add it to the truststore Chrome uses, and that varies depending on what OS/platform you are on, which you didn't say.

Comment: Thanks Dave. It was useful. I also got the idea from other references how to add the certificate manually to truststore of chrome.